# In numpy, how can we detect uint32/int32 overflow or underflow?

Tags: python, numpy

I was surprised that even setting np.seterr(all='raise') doesn't seem to trigger overflow/underflow errors for int32, despite the documentation seeming to say that these settings for floats will also be applied to integer types.

Is this just the cost of doing business with fast processing, or is there some automatic way to detect underflow/overflow? I thought the ALUs had some flag that made it easy to detect...

```
import numpy as np
np.seterr(all='raise')

x = np.array(10,dtype=np.uint32)

y = np.array(100,dtype=np.uint32)

z = x-y

print(z) #=> 4294967206
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed just the cost of doing fast processing. See the [relevant bug case](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/8987).